# WordPress or Community Server or N2?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, content-management

I am starting a website where i would like to post technical articles. I am looking for a system that helps me post code easily, is optimized for Search engines and is easy to use and operate.

For now, I don't have any plan of having a forum in there, maybe in the future.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay with a .Net back end, rather than full Community Server you could try [BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/).  Source is available in c#, and there is a code formatting addin included.

If you are not hosting on a Microsoft server then I would probably second Darth's suggestion and go with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

**WordPress** is good to start with. It has convenient administration and is easy to setup and use. And there's whole bunch of plugins for almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you could also have a look at [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) ([Codeplex Download](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/)). Install is straight forward, with a community to help you with any issues.

Just add a page and paste your code into the text/html module and voila, done.

Granted it will not format your code in pwerty colours but it will do what you require. This is VB.NET code so will require IIS/SQL Server combination if that is within your system preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress with the "wp-syntax" plugin makes for some nice code highlighting.

It uses GeSHi highlighting, so you simply need to do something like the below:

```
<pre lang="PHP">
    // code
</pre>
```

As it's based upon GeSHi, it supports a lot more and is nicer to copy and paste than Google Code Prettify.

In regards to the "dated" nature of Wordpress, this can be changed relevant to theme (that is, how important you make the date) and through changing the permalinks. For example "http://example.com/article/" is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Mediawiki for posting code (there are some nice source highlighting plugins), especially as code articles generally aren't date specific like blog posts on WordPress migh tbe.